In Z3, how does one chain existence and implication without needing to specify all datatypes explicitly?
I'm trying to convert a model I created in Alloy to Z3, and am having a trouble figuring out how to properly set up implication and existence of arbitrary entities.
Background:  I'm trying to model cloud network topologies, so IGWs, VPCs, subnets, etc. I want to be able to request my model to generate say 100x ec2 instances, and M of them have permission X, N has access Y, and some other O have exposure Z, and use my of constraints to generate this!
I'm able to create reasonably complex topologies in Alloy that show EC2 instances with various network properties and permissions (and convert this into Terraform and then create real topologies), but my model starts hitting various scale issues no matter how I've tuned it. Specifically, I can only add around 10 ec2 instances and all the related constructs before things blow up. It has been recommended to me by people much more familiar with formal methods that Z3 is worth a look.
In Alloy, a simple version of my model looks like so, where I specify that I want some "connected" and "unconnected" instances of sig A. I define isConnected which says that if an A is connected, that means that the A that the A is points to is also pointed to by a C:
sig A {
    b: B
}

sig B {
}


sig C {
    b: B
}

pred isConnected[a: A] {
    some c: C | a.b = c.b
}

run {
    some a: A | isConnected[a]
    some a: A | not isConnected[a]
}

In Z3, I'm confused as to how to model any of this! I can set up my datatypes, and that seems fine, following this:
class B:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

class C:
    b: b
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.b = None

class A:
    b: B
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.b = None

The first part I'm stuck on is defining isConnected: I'd like it to take a single argument of type A, and then say if a of type A is connected, that implies there exists some c of type C where a.b = c.b. I'd rather not have to instantiate Cs (or Bs) myself; given how many As I want the model should just figure it out. The below is my obviously incorrect function:
def isConnected(a: A):
    return Implies(Exists(c), And(a.b = c.b))

The second part is once I can do the above, what's the best way to specify "give me 2 connected As, and 2 unconnected As"? Is it as simple as this?
a1 = A('a1')
a2 = A('a2')
a3 = A('a3')
a4 = A('a4')

s = Solver()
s.add(isConnected(a1))
s.add(isConnected(a2))
s.add(Not(isConnected(a3)))
s.add(Not(isConnected(a4)))
...

Thanks!

There could be multiple ways to solve this problem, but thinking like "Alloy" and coding in "SMTLib" is probably leading you astray. Look at how quantifiers are used in SMTLib. You can then either directly use that, or use transitive-clousure relations in z3 to help you.
